# Использование модальных окон

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, modal

Есть страничка на которой вызывается модальное окно с таблицей, в которой много записей. Соответственно на странице появляется скролл. Далее в этом окне я вызываю ещё одно модальное окно с помощью `ajax` запроса, выкидываю его в `div`, который находится на первом модальном окне. И после закрытия второго модального окна первое остаётся, но на нём пропадает скролл.

При выполнении этих манипуляций я зашёл на отладку клиента в хроме и увидел, что при открытии модального окна у `body` появляется класс `modal-open`. При открытии второго модального окна этот класс сохраняется. А вот если зарыть второе модальное окно, но оставить первое открытым, тогда класс `modal-open` у `body` пропадает.

Попробовал закрыть второе модальное окно и оставить первое открытым и сам в ручную через отладку клиента добавил телу этот класс, скролл появился. Как можно сделать так, чтобы этот класс сохранятся, если хоть какое-то модальное окно ещё открыто? Ну то есть мне нужно, чтобы скролл оставался если он был.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так на событие `on('hidden')` или `on('hidden.bs.modal')`:

```
$('.modal').each((i) => {
    if ($(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open'));
    } else $('body').addClass('modal-open'));
});
```

Comment: Kvilios, сделал, но мне этот способ костыльным кажется.

Comment: Может как то можно на самой модалке сделать css стили и там присваивать в боди класс moda-open с помощью чисто css?